# Can't access the firebase object

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I can see I've the script in the `head`, I get this error "error. 'firebase' is not defined (no-undef)". Why can't I use the firebase object?

```
mounted() {
  let recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script');
  recaptchaScript.setAttribute(
    'src',
    'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js'
  );
  document.head.appendChild(recaptchaScript);

  console.log('firebase is: ', firebase);

  // this.initFirebase();
},
```

Comment: I would check to see where and when you import the script in the head. Make sure you put it **before** your vue script

Comment: @DavidBuzatu How can it be a race condition, when I have the console right after the DOM injection? Do I need to wait a tick before it works or something like that?

Comment: I have seen someone running into a similar problem and I thought it may help. This is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40433612/11023871)